# How is it possible to define a equation, differentiate and plot it, using Sympy in Jupyter Nootebook?

Tags: python, plot, jupyter-notebook, sympy, differentiation

In Jupyter Notebook i would like to define a equation, differentiate and plot the equation.

```
import sympy as sp
from IPython.display import display
sp.init_printing()
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

x = sp.symbols('x')

def func(x):
    a= sp.sympify("4/5")
    return (x**3+a*x**2)
display(func(x))

def dfunc(x):
    a = sp.diff(func(x),x)
    return a
display(dfunc(x))


x = np.linspace(-10,10,20)


plt.plot(x,func(x))
plt.plot(x,dfunc(x))      # doesn't work
```

`display(dfunc(x))` shows the wanted function but `plt.plot(x,dfunc(x))` returns the error message `ValueError: cannot derive by this array`

Does anyone know how to get the plot?

(It also doesn't work with `sp.integrate(func(x),x)` instead of `sp.diff(func(x),x)`. Just another error message is returned `ValueError: Invalid limits given: ...`)

Many thanks in advance.

Matthias

Comment: if you don't need analytic results, drop sympy and use numerics only.

Comment: unfortunately i need the analytic results for further calulations.

Comment: Careful.  You first define `x` as a symbol.  But then redefine it as a numpy array.  `func` and `dfunc` should work with the symbol - test that.  But I don't expect them to work with the array.  Until you know what you are doing, don't mix sympy with numpy/scipy/matplotlib.  Eventually you can use `sympy.lambdify`, but for now stick with sympy.

Comment: I just tried lambdify and it also works. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the SymPy `plot` function rather than the `matplotlib` one. The matplotlib plot function expects arrays as inputs whereas the sympy one accepts sympy expressions (and then calculates values to make the arrays for matplotlib):

```
In [36]: import sympy as sym

In [37]: a = sym.Rational(4, 5)

In [38]: x = sym.Symbol('x')

In [39]: f = x**3 + a*x**2

In [40]: f
Out[40]: 
        2
 3   4⋅x 
x  + ────
      5  

In [41]: f.diff(x)
Out[41]: 
   2   8⋅x
3⋅x  + ───
        5 

In [42]: sym.plot(f.diff(x))
```